# Why Typo3 generates poor quality by convert PNG to PNG with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, debian, typo3, imagemagick-convert, gdlib

All my sites works fine, after some updates in the last weeks I realize that the quality of PNG are very bad. I use Typo3 4.5.27 and imagemagick 6.6.0.4, Typo3 called following command:

/usr/local/bin/convert -strip -geometry 150x120!   /var/www/introductionpackage-4.5.27/typo3/sysext/install/imgs/jesus2_transp.png[0] /var/www/introductionpackage-4.5.27/typo3temp/pics/install_scale_png.png

This is the output of this command

[image]

And this is the refference Image:

[image]

Can anybody explain what is wrong? Any suggestion to solve or debug the problem?

I try to update the imagemagick to current version but I still have this issue.

This is GFX section in localconf

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['gdlib_2'] = '0';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_combine_filename'] = 'composite';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_version_5'] = 'im6';        
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_path_lzw'] = '/usr/local/bin/';     
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_imvMaskState'] = '1';      
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_negate_mask'] = '0';       
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/';       
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_stripProfileCommand'] = '-strip';   
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['png_truecolor'] = '1'; 
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_v5effects'] = '0';  
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['gdlib_png'] = '1'
```

Under Basic Configuration of Typo3 is following Content under GDLIB Section:

[image]

Comment: Please check if "png_truecolor" is set to true in install tool -> all configuration.

Comment: png_truecolor is set to TRUE, I edit my question.

Comment: It looks like the image just uses 256 colors like GIF does. What about `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['gdlib_png'] = '1';`. Check the settings in "Basic Configurations".

Comment: Yes, and it looks like a error with the Background, too. The Background is not transparent. I set $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['gdlib_png'] = '1' in the localconf but nothing will changed.

Comment: What Setting especially you mean in the basic configuration?

Comment: Make sure, that you've cleared you **typo3temp** directory after changes to _GFX_ section, because, TYPO3 doesn't regenerate an images in Install Tool, but takes existing ones instead.

Comment: I use the "scaling images" Option under "Image Processing", this will not access to the typo3temp directory. But I clean the temp directory too.

Answer (score 0):

since the branch from ImageMagick many improvements have been made. It can also be installed over ftp if there is no shell access. http://wiki.typo3.org/GraphicsMagick